# Error on SQL count into ExecuteScalar()

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, executescalar

When executing the below code I get the following error.

```
"Additional information: Conversion from string "_01202478334" to type 'Double' is not valid."
```

Code:

```
          Using connn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("server=inlt01\SQLEXPRESS; database=DaisyServices; integrated security=yes")
          Using cmdz As SqlClient.SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()

          cmdz.CommandText = "SELECT CLI, FromDate, ToDate, [Description], TotalCost, COUNT(*) as Count FROM [" + FileNameOnly + "] GROUP BY CLI, FromDate, ToDate, [Description], TotalCost HAVING COUNT(*) > 1"
          connn.Open()

          If cmdz.ExecuteScalar() > 1 Then

          'Error if name in use
          MessageBox.Show("Duplicate records exist on imported file!!")
```

In order to troubleshoot I removed the CLI field, but then I get a new error

```
"Additional information: Operator '>' is not defined for type 'Date' and type 'Integer'"
```

I am using some very similar code on a separate form and it runs without any error.

Here is my working code:

```
          Using connn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("server=inlt01\SQLEXPRESS; database=DaisyBilling; integrated security=yes")
          Using cmdz As SqlClient.SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()

          cmdz.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerCLI, calldate, calltime, duration, TelephoneNumber, COUNT(*) as Count FROM [" + FileNameOnly + "] GROUP BY CustomerCLI, calldate, calltime, duration, TelephoneNumber HAVING COUNT(*) > 1"
          connn.Open()

          If cmdz.ExecuteScalar() > 1 Then

          'Error if name in use
          MessageBox.Show("Duplicate records exist on imported file!!")
```

How come the code works on my other form, but not on this one?

NB. The SQL executes ok if I run the query direct from SQL server

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: `ExecuteScalar` is intended for when the query returns one value only. If you put the `count` as the first element in your `SELECT`, it may work.

Comment: Thanks you, that worked! Happy to mark as Answered if you want to add below. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExecuteScalar` is intended more for when the query returns one value only. If you put the `count` as the first element in your `SELECT`, it will work.

From the documentation for [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx):

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.